# What does Doppler Fast/Slow Items? How do they relate to Micro-Doppler Signature?

Tags: radar, doppler

I'm working with X4M200 respiration sensor ([Sensor Output Datatypes](https://github.com/novelda/Legacy-Documentation/blob/master/Application-Notes/XTAN-05_XeThruFileFormats-v2.pdf)) and in provided link on page 11 it says that it provides recordings with Movement Slow/Fast Items (slow and fast pulsedoppler matrix). As I want to use this sensor to detect different kinds of movement, I find that would be useful.

[In this paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4148281), as well as in other papers I've seen researchers use Micro-Doppler signatures to differentiate between different kinds of movements.

My question is twofold.

1. Could Pulsedoppler matrices be enough to recognize different kinds of movement?
2. If not, is there a way to get Micro-Doppler Signatures form Pulsedoppler matrices?

Please let me know If I'm not making sense somehow. I will correct my question.

Comment: Hi Robert and welcome to DSP.SE! I suspect as written your question is far too broad, and unless someone is already familiar with this specific sensor, would require a lot of additional time to read your links and papers, and to get to the root of what your more detailed questions may be. Do you have any specific questions within the links and references that wouldn't require someone else to read all that?

Comment: It would be possible to answer your two questions directly, but you also mention the slow/fast "items". I read the sheet, but it's ambiguous as to what they mean by fast/slow matrices. It's possible that they're referring to two matrices captured by low and high PRF waveforms.